# SPDYCheck says "yay", but my browser says "nay"?

Tags: nginx, https, openssl, google-chrome, spdy

SPDYcheck.org gives the thumbs up all round, with its only criticism being

```
Out-of-Date SPDY Protocol Support
The most recent version of SPDY is spdy/3. The highest version this website 
supports is spdy/2. There are 3 major versions of SPDY. This website should 
consider updating its software if possible to support spdy/3.
```

(Nginx 1.5.6, openSSL 1.0.1e - both latest versions I think, how could I get spdy/3 if I wanted it?)

But when I check it in my browser, through

```
chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active
```

it doesn't show up.  Other sites like google et al DO.

I also installed a chrome extension that puts a green lightning bolt in the address bar if SPDY is detected.  Google = green bolt.  My site = no green bolt.

I tried https://isspdyenabled.com/ to double-test my browser, and it told me that

```
This connection uses SPDY_VERSION: 3
```

So is the problem that my browser is refusing to use spdy/2 when it wants to use spdy/3 instead?

Or am I maybe using some cipher suite that is incompatible with SPDY, if that's even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html), nginx only supports SPDY/2.

Why your site does not show as SPDY enabled, you gave too little information (no config files, etc.).

If you want a server that supports SPDY/3 you can look into [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) ([documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html)), which also does SPDY Push with [these results](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/).

Apache HTTPD also supports SPDY/3 via [mod_spdy](http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/), but to my knowledge does not do SPDY Push automatically like Jetty does.

Comment: I was hoping for a pointer as to what tools/methods I should use to debug this and get to the bottom of it.  But I think it was just down to me using an alpha version of Chrome.

Comment: @Codemonkey You should have clearly mentioned what you are hoping for in the question to answer it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in my canary release of Chrome.  On my laptop on a stable release it works fine.